# Mongoid Polymorphic Association + FactoryGirl + RSpec

Tags: mongoid, factory-bot

I'm trying to embed emails inside person Mongoid object using polymorphic approach. Getting "BSON::InvalidDocument: Cannot serialize an object of class Mongoid::Relations::Embedded::Many into BSON." whenever I run the test.  Please see code below and any will be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure what is correct way to build emails inside person in FactoryGirl. Thanks.

```
class Email
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  embedded_in :mailable, polymorphic: true

  field :email, type: String
  field :category, type: String
end

class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :emails, as: :mailable       #polymorhpic
  index  "emails.email", unique: true

  field :first_name, type: String
  field :middle_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String

  validates_uniqueness_of :emails

end


FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:fn) {|n| "first_name#{n}" }
  sequence(:ln) {|n| "last_name#{n}" }
  factory :person do
    first_name { generate(:fn) }
    last_name { generate(:ln) }
    gender 'M'
    nationality 'USA'
    ssn '123-88-1111'
    factory :emails_ do
      emails { Factory.build(:email) }
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:address) {|n| "user#{n}@mail.com" }
  factory :email do
    email { generate(:address) }
    category 'personal'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach I took when last using Factory Girl with embedded associations in mongoid. Try this in your user factory instead.

```
emails { |e| [e.association(:email)] }
```